# how to put coordinates in geojson file on a tabular form using python?

Tags: python, geojson

```
{"features":[{"geometry":{"coordinates":[[-73.99724821539623,40.74719271050628],[-73.99727125011154,40.747160943397745]],"type":"LineString"},"properties":{"metadata":{"curb_id":"bnljOjIxOTIw","distance_end_meters":4.034743205134495,"end_street_name":"WEST 25 STREET","side_of_street":"NW","start_street_name":"WEST 26 STREET","street_name":"8 AVENUE","time_zone":"America/New_York"},"price":null,"reasons":["intersection"],"uses":{"permitted":null,"use":"none","vehicle_type":"all"}},"type":"Feature"},"type":"FeatureCollection"}
```

This is the small portion of the geojson file that I have. It should work fine. Problem is I can't put the coordinates into tabular form.[image]

Comment: Please share code, NO picture